# C style strings in iOS app get corrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, string

I am building an iOS app in which I have a number of CPP files with C-style char strings.

I have a file defined as:

```
#define str1 "str1"
#define str2 "str2"

typedef struct {
    const char *s;
    int i;
} ArrayType;

ArrayType array[] = {
    str1, 1,
    str2, 2
};
```

When running the app, I see the data in strings str1 and str2 getting corrupted. The int values 1 and 2 however are fine. I'm wondering if this is related to how strings are handled in Object-C and iOS projects?

I even tried making the .cpp file into an Objective-C++ source and changed the code as follows:

```
#define str1 "str1"
#define str2 "str2"

typedef struct {
    const char *s;
    int i;
} ArrayType;

NSString *s1 = @str1;
NSString *s2 = @str2;

ArrayType array[] = {
    s1, 1,
    s2, 2
};
```

Any clues regarding this behavior?

Comment: How are you checking the contents? Objective-C is only a layer over C and there is absolutely no difference in handling of C strings (arrays of characters). Please add the code that is checking the contents of `array`.

Comment: Those strings are in the constant pool, so they shouldn't get overwritten. I would recommend setting a breakpoint on write of `array[0].s` and seeing what's altering the string value there.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` will always give a `NSString`. So, In your C code, you need to convert `NSString` to C string like

```
#define str1 @"str1"
#define str2 @"str2"

typedef struct {
    const char *s;
    int i;
} ArrayType;

ArrayType array[] = {
    [str1 cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding], 1,
    [str2 cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding], 2
};
```

Now Regarding your objective C code I observed a mistake in `NSString *s1 = @str1;`. It should be `NSString *s1 = @"str1";`, I think you missed the quotes `"`.

Hope this will help you ....

Comment: How is this supposed to work? ArrayType specifically has const char * as the type for s. This will result in a compilation error, since initWithUTF8String would return an NSString object.

Comment: Why would `#define` return anything? `#define` is a replacement and `"..."` will stay a C-string. To make it a `NSString` you would have to add a `@`.

Comment: @NJGadhiya Still it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @NJGadhiya "#define will always give a NSString" is a completely incorrect statement. Your answer doesn't make sense then.